# How to convert URL to MP3 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, web, mp3

I just extracted a video link from a website which, actually, is a link to audio file. As in, it's an audio only but video format.

So I am trying to make it easy for user to get the file as MP3. Is there a way to do that with javascript or PHP?

Here is the link: http://streaming.patari.pk/video/c4e216fd-0c30-4fbd-aff8-60cb671c66ed.mp4

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Here is the link http://streaming.patari.pk/video/c4e216fd-0c30-4fbd-aff8-60cb671c66ed.mp4

Comment: You don't "convert a URL to MP3", you download the media from a URL and then transcode it.